# insert column with same row content to csv in cli

Tags: linux, csv, unix, command-line-interface

I am having a csv to which I need to add a new column at the end and add a certain string to all rows of the csv in the newly added column.

Example csv:

```
os,num1,alpha1
Unix,10,A
Linux,30,B
Solaris,40,C
Fedora,20,D
Ubuntu,50,E
```

I tried using awk command and did not get expected result. I am not sure whether indexing or counting column number is right.

```
awk -F'[[:null:]]' '$2 && !$1{ $4="NA" }1'
```

Expected result is:

```
os,num1,alpha1,code
Unix,10,A,NA
Linux,30,B,NA
Solaris,40,C,NA
Fedora,20,D,NA
Ubuntu,50,E,NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/):

```
sed 's/$/,NA/' db1.csv > db2.csv
```

then edit the first line containing the column titles.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how you came up w/ that awk statement of yours, why you'd think that your file has `NUL`-terminated lines or that `[[:null:]]` has become a valid character class ...

The following, however, will do your bidding:

```
awk 'NR==1{print $0",code"}; NR>1{print $0",NA"}' example.csv
os,num1,alpha1,code
Unix,10,A,NA
Linux,30,B,NA
Solaris,40,C,NA
Fedora,20,D,NA
Ubuntu,50,E,NA
```

Comment: I added the column name using sed and as there were empty rows I was trying to look was null. I am new to awk and sed. Both of your answers works fine. But is there a way I can rewrite the existing file instead of creating new file?

Comment: With the `sed` version you could use `-i`  (in place) ... but that doesn't do the label row properly (no "code" at the end, but also a NA).

Comment: Worked great after adding sed -i. Thank you.